# Google Adsense consent form not displayed unless I explicitly state /index.html in the URL

Tags: javascript, adsense, google-ads-script, fundingchoices

I have this simple HTML site deployed on `example.com` (via Github Pages). I have Google Adsense enabled.

When I enter `example.com/index.html` on the browser, the Google Adsense consent form (Funding Choices) is properly displayed when loading. However, it doesn't when I simply enter `example.com`. No errors are displayed on the console. I see in the script is downloaded well (via DevTools), but the consent form is never displayed.

The website was created with create-react-app but I was able to reproduce this issue with just the index.html and an empty index.js being deployed.

Any thoughts?

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>     
    <!-- Adsense -->
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXX"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div>Hello World!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide link to your site, if it's public?